# How to prevent this circular reference in Flask/SQLAlchemy Models?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, circular-dependency, flask-migrate

I have the following four model classes in my Flask/SQLAlchemy application (a fifth class `MyClassA` is not shown here but is reference):

```
class MyClassF(db.Model):
    valid_fs = ['F1', 'F2']
    f_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Enum(*valid_fs, name='f_enum'), default='F1', nullable=False)

class MyClassD(db.Model):
    d_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    v_collection = db.relationship('MyClassV', lazy='dynamic', backref=db.backref('d'), cascade='all, delete-orphan')

class MyClassV(db.Model):
    v_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    d_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(MyClassD.d_id), nullable=False)
    c_collection = db.relationship('MyClassC', lazy='dynamic', backref=db.backref('v'), cascade='all, delete-orphan')
    a_collection = db.relationship('MyClassA', lazy='dynamic', backref=db.backref('v'), cascade='all, delete-orphan')

class MyClassC(db.Model):
    c_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    v_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(MyClassV.v_id), nullable=False)
    f_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey(MyClassF.f_id),
        nullable=False,
        #default=MyClassF.query.filter(MyClassF.name == "F1").one().f_id
    )
```

Creating this schema using the [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) command `db init`, `db migrate` and `db upgrade` works just fine.

However, when I un-comment the line the definition of `MyClassC.f_id` and try it again (after removing the `migrations` directory), I get the following circular dependency error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper
>   Mapper|MyClassV|my_classV, expression 'MyClassC' failed to locate a
>   name ("name 'MyClassC' is not defined"). If this is a class name,
>   consider adding this relationship() to the 
>   class after both dependent classes have been defined.

All I'm trying to do is ensure that the default value of `MyClassC.f_id` is set by querying the `MyClassF` table. This check should occur at insertion time -- not when the database is being created. So I don't understand why I am getting this error now.

How can I use `db.relationship()` (or any other technique) to get around this circular dependency error while enforcing the database integrity rule I'm trying to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the default parameter is translated to the [SQL `DEFAULT` constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp). AFAICT this constraint is not evaluated at insertion time, but when creating the table and the value is then used as a default (which means the default value is set once and forall at creation of the table and used for all rows that lack that column, it cannot dynamically change according to the contents of an other table).

However [the documentation of SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#python-executed-functions) mentions the fact that you can pass in a python *function* as default value and it will be called for each insert to obtain the default value to use, so you can do:

```
class MyClassC(db.Model):
    c_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    v_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(MyClassV.v_id), nullable=False)
    f_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey(MyClassF.f_id),
        nullable=False,
        default=lambda: MyClassF.query.filter(MyClassF.name == "F1").one().f_id
    )
```

Note however that this will *not* use any database facility to provide the default value, it's SQLAlchemy first obtaining the default value and then manually inserting it in your queries.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you!